# Using ng-repeat to display only one row of data-Ionic app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

Sorry for any mistakes in advanced, but I'm new here.  Codepen http://codepen.io/erinbelldeveloper/pen/pyZxZB

I'm trying to create an appointment app that displays the data from the footer once you push it to the list card. My issue is with the output of the data I just want it to output the last line inputted by the user not the entire data so I figured the issue was with the ng-repeat so I wrote this line to the code  which yes it only shows one row but then it removes the prior data. Without those div lines it outputs a loop with all the data. Ideally I want to output the last line only if the message content has more than 1 row but keeping the prior data.

```
  <ion-view class="appointments-view">
  <ion-nav-title>
    <span>Appointments</span>
  </ion-nav-title>

 <ion-content class="content-stable"
                 on-swipe-left="hideTime = false"
                 on-swipe-right="hideTime = true"  ng-controller="appointmentsController">
      </br></br>

    <div class="list card" >
      <div class="item item-divider">Appointment List </br></br>
         <label class="weekly">Weekly Dates:  </label>    
        <div class="apptdates">
 <input id="start"  type="date" ng-model="appoinment.startdate"/><input id="end" type="date" ng-model="appointment.enddate" />
    </div>
    <div class="item item-body">
       <table id="appointmentTable2" class="displaytable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <tbody>

                <tr>
                <th>{{message.date}}</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Appointment Name</th>
                <th>Appointment Date</th>
                <th>Appointment Time</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>

         <div ng-repeat="message in messages"
           ng-class="{other: message.userId != myId}" 
           class="messages"><div ng-show="$last">
           <div ng-repeat="message2 in messages2"
           ng-class="{other: message2.userId != myId}" 
           class="messages2"><div ng-show="$last">
           <div ng-repeat="message3 in messages3"
           ng-class="{other: message3.userId != myId}"
           class="messages3"><div ng-show="$last">
           <div ng-repeat="message4 in messages4"
           ng-class="{other: message4.userId != myId}"
           class="messages4"><div ng-show="$last">

        <div class="message" ng-class="{'slide-right': hideTime, '': !hideTime}">
         <div class="message2" ng-class="{'slide-right': hideTime, '': !hideTime}">
          <div class="message3" ng-class="{'slide-right': hideTime, '': !hideTime}">
           <div class="message4" ng-class="{'slide-right': hideTime, '': !hideTime}">
        <div class="time" ng-class="{'slide-right': hideTime, '': !hideTime}">
        <div class="date" ng-class="{'slide-right': hideTime, '': !hideTime}">

           <table id="appointmentTable2" class="displaytable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Appointment Name</th>
                <th>Appointment Date</th>
                <th>Appointment Time</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
       <th><span >{{ message.date }}</span></th>
       <th><span>{{message.time}}</span></th>
       <th><span>{{message.text}}</span></th>
       <th><span>{{message2.text}}</span></th>
       <th><span>{{message3.text}}</span></th>
       <th><span>{{message4.text}}</span></th>
       <th><i class="icon ion-checkmark-circled positive large" id="statusicon" ui-sref="home.results"></i></th>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
          </div> </div></div> </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>

         </br></br></br></br></br></br>
         </div>

          <table id="appointmentTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">  
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Appointment Name</th>
                <th>Appointment Date</th>
                <th>Appointment Time</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>

      </div>

       </div>


        </br></br></br></br></br></br></br>

      <ion-footer-bar keyboard-attach class="bar-stable item-input-inset">

       Create Appointment </br>

      <label class="item-input-wrapper">
    </br>
       <table id="appointmentTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">  
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name " on-return="sendMessage(); closeKeyboard()" ng-model="data.message" on-focus="inputUp()" on-blur="inputDown()" /></th>
                <th><input type="text" placeholder="Appointment Name " on-return="sendMessage(); closeKeyboard()"  ng-model="data.message2" on-focus="inputUp()" on-blur="inputDown()" /></th>
                <th><input type="text" placeholder="Appointment Date " on-return="sendMessage(); closeKeyboard()"  ng-model="data.message3"  on-focus="inputUp()" on-blur="inputDown()"/></th>
                <th><input type="text" placeholder="Appointment Time" on-return="sendMessage(); closeKeyboard()"  ng-model="data.message4" on-focus="inputUp()" on-blur="inputDown()" /></th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>

      </label>

       <i class="icon ion-plus-circled positive large" id="addicon" ng-click="sendMessage()"></i>

    </ion-footer-bar>
        </ion-content>      
</ion-view>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('App')


.controller('appointmentsController', function($scope, $timeout, $ionicScrollDelegate) {

  $scope.hideTime = true;

  var alternate,
    isIOS = ionic.Platform.isWebView() && ionic.Platform.isIOS();


 $scope.sendMessage = function() {
    alternate = !alternate;

    var d = new Date();
    var c=new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
  d = d.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d+ /, ' ');

    $scope.messages.push({
      userId: alternate ? '12345' : '54321',
      text: $scope.data.message,
      time: d,
      date: c
    });
     $scope.messages2.push({
      userId: alternate ? '12345' : '54321',
      text: $scope.data.message2,
      time: d,
      date: c
    });
     $scope.messages3.push({
      userId: alternate ? '12345' : '54321',
      text: $scope.data.message3,
      time: d,
      date: c
    });
     $scope.messages4.push({
      userId: alternate ? '12345' : '54321',
      text: $scope.data.message4,
      time: d,
      date: c
    });


    delete $scope.data.message;
    delete $scope.data.message2;
    delete $scope.data.message3;
    delete $scope.data.message4;
    $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom(true);

  };








  $scope.inputUp = function() {
    if (isIOS) $scope.data.keyboardHeight = 216;
    $timeout(function() {
      $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom(true);
    }, 300);

  };

  $scope.inputDown = function() {
    if (isIOS) $scope.data.keyboardHeight = 0;
    $ionicScrollDelegate.resize();
  };

  $scope.closeKeyboard = function() {
    // cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close();
  };


  $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data1 = {};
  $scope.myId = '12345';
  $scope.messages = [];
   $scope.messages2 = [];
    $scope.messages3 = [];
     $scope.messages4 = [];



});
```

Comment: can you simplify this or create a codePen showing the issue?

Comment: http://codepen.io/erinbelldeveloper/pen/pyZxZB

Comment: Just navigate to appointments in the menu or through the dashboard

Comment: not following the logic here and the inclusion of all of the nested loops